# How to bind .env values in Laravel Service using Service Container and Service Provider

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, laravel-8, laravel-service-container

What I want to achieve is I have a service class name '**SmsService**'

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

use App\Contracts\SmsServiceContract;
use App\Models\Student;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

    class SmsService implements SmsServiceContract{
    
            private $account_sid;
            private $account_token;
            private $account_from;
            private $reciever;
    
            public function __construct(){
                $this->account_sid = env("TWILIO_SID");
                $this->account_token = env("TWILIO_TOKEN");
                $this->account_from = env("TWILIO_FROM");
                $this->reciever = new Client($this->account_sid, $this->account_token);
            }
    
        public function sendSingleSms($phone_number, $message){
            
            $this->reciever->messages->create($phone_number,[
                'from' => $this->account_from,
                'body' => $message
            ]);
        }
    
    }
```

I'm binding this service in a service container like this.

```
$this->app->bind(SmsServiceContract::class, SmsService::class);
```

The issue is that I'm getting `null` when I'm trying to get `TWILIO_SID` from `.env` file.
How could I get `.env` data in SmsService class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never access env variables directly in your application, but only through config files.

The best place to put these is in `config/services.php`

Add a section for Twilio;

```
    'twilio' => [
        'sid' => env('TWILIO_SID'),
        'token => env('TWILIO_TOKEN'),
        'from' => env('TWILIO_FROM'),
    ]
```

then open tinker and run

```
>>> config('services.twilio')
```

and check that the values are all represented there as expected.

Then in your service provider change references to env() for config and using the dot separated names. eg;

```
    public function __contruct(){
       $this->account_sid = config('services.twilio.sid');
       $this->account_token = config('services.twilio.token');
       $this->account_from = config('services.twilio.from);
```

finally, make sure you bind your class into the container via the register() method of a service provider.

Comment: I think it's important to mention, that if you use `php artisan config:cache` the env variables will only updated if you run this command again.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 first time config/app.php
  edit 
  add this line
 'account_sid' => env('TWILIO_SID'),
 'account_token' => env('TWILIO_TOKEN'),
 'account_from' => env('TWILIO_FROM'),

and change this line 

 public function __contruct(){
                $this->account_sid = config('app.account_sid');
                $this->account_token = config('app.account_token');
                $this->account_from = config('app.account_from');
                $this->reciever = new Client($this->account_sid, $this->account_token);
            }

because you are production mode runnig
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already tried this but still, it's giving null.

Comment: php artisan config:clear try pls

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To access keys from .env file, best way is to access them through **congif/app.php** file.
Add these lines in Config/app.php

```
 'Account_SID' => env('TWILIO_SID'),
 'Account_token' => env('TWILIO_TOKEN'),
 'Account_from' => env('TWILIO_FROM'),
```

in **SmsService** you can access them as

```
     public function __contruct(){
        $this->account_sid = config('app.Account_SID');
        $this->account_token =config('app.Account_token');
        $this->account_from = config('app.Account_from');
        $this->reciever = new Client($this->account_sid, $this->account_token);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this is not working. As per laravel documentation Service Container did not bind config values implicitly.